# Adding RSS feed to a site using javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bigcommerce

I have a wordpress site and an ecommerce site using BigCommerce (which uses Stencil template language) so I can't use any PHP on the ecommerce site.

I would like to show the 3 most recent blog posts on our ecommerce landing page, using javascript, something like this:

```
<script src="//www.mysite.com/custom.js"></script> <div class="some-blog-class" id="some-blog-id"></div>
```

I know this is possible because there is a service that offers this exact thing, however 1) they don't show images and 2) they charge $10/mo.

Is this something I can tackle on my own? Is it far more difficult than I think?

If it helps, the company's javascript can be found here: http://www.powr.io/powr.js and their exact embed code is:

```
<script src="//www.powr.io/powr.js" external-type=bigcommerce></script> <div class="powr-rss-feed" id="db3866bb_1512149832"></div>
```

Comment: Can't you just pop a Recent Posts widget on your page?

Comment: @jmargolisvt OP said "I can't use any PHP on the ecommerce site." So no. TBH if you already have a WordPress site I would recommend moving to WooCommerce and dropping BigCommerce as fast as possible. You will save a lot of money in the long run and have a lot more power over your site.

Comment: @Kallmanation opinions matter ( or do they?) ^_^  You say Woocommerce, I say magento/xcart.. somebody will come up with something else. The thing is, the best software for you is the one that actually works for you ;)